# Is there any way to stitch 3 pdfs into one page of pdf?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

I a going to make an app to help me in my job. I need to connect 3 pdf files into one page (each file has height 1/3 of A4 paper).
Only thing I was able to achieve was to append pdfs and get one file with 3 pages. I'm not asking for a complete code. I will appreciate if You can show me the way (what libraries, tips how to approach this problem). I am using python 3. Thanks guys in advance for any help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files)

Comment: Very similar to question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589593/join-multiple-pdf-files-into-a-single-page-pdf-positioned-join-using-php